# return a query SELECT statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Im trying to return all the id from authors Table... but isnt working... Just returning me the first ID... But if i delete the return and put to Print, that give me all IDs..

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb";
String user = "test";
String password = "test*";

try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM authors");
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        return rs.getInt(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement by default returns the value of the returned constant/variable, stops the method execution and leave the method. This is explained here: [Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

To return all the results from the execution of your query, you must store the results in a `List` and then return this list:

```
List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//accessing to the database and executing the query...
rs = pst.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    //store the ids in the list
    idList.add(rs.getInt(1));
}
//close all the resources...
//at the bottom of your method
return idList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Return play the role of `break` in this case , i suggest to return `ResultSet` and iterate over it using for or `iterator` in the View.

```
    while (rs.next()) {
        return rs;
    }
```

And in the view:

```
 while (nameOfYourFunction().next()) {
            System.Out.println( rs);
        }
```

Comment: Building a `List`, cleaning up resources, and returning the `List` would be nicer than leaking the ResultSet and leaving resources open...

Comment: @Glenn it depends on the nature and complexity of his query , if it was more big , he will nead to create Beans and then storing them in arrayList , i think it's more annoying

Comment: The cleanest solution is to **always** close the resources after consuming them

Answer (score 0):

`return` terminates your method call, as it denotes that this is the value, that the method was supposed to compute. Only the first `return` call in your method will ever get executed. So if you are planning on getting all the results from your query, you should return a collection of all those ids, which you construct before calling `return` with it.